# PHP , jQuery and AJAX Automatically starting an event

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make an online bidding website using PHP. I'm trying to start a bid on given time automatically. I can do this if the web page is opened using jquery and AJAX. But I want to do it automatically without through server. Is there any method for doing this?

Comment: try using a cron command and some websokets to get the start of the event on the page

Comment: I agree a cron-job should be the best solution. But, what exactly do you require to do to `start the bid`

Comment: a php file that saves the date for the bid start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a php file to start a bid on given time and then execute/run it by adding it as a cron job through hosting panel.

Comment: Note that Cron is only on Linux servers - on Windows server you must use any alternative...

Comment: Some hosts provide ' schedule tasks' functionality for windows server that is similar to cron job scheduling on Linux. e.g GoDaddy Plesk shared hosting.